# jfrog cli error "wrong number of arguments" when running jfrog rt config

Tags: artifactory, jfrog-cli

I'm using the following command in a CI pipeline that builds a Docker container:

`RUN curl -fL https://getcli.jfrog.io | sh \
    && mv jfrog /usr/local/bin/jfrog \
    && jfrog rt config --interactive false --url https://artifactory.myorg.com/artifactory`

which is failing with error: **[Error] Wrong number of arguments.**:

```
Step 8/11 : RUN curl -fL https://getcli.jfrog.io | sh     && mv jfrog /usr/local/bin/jfrog     && jfrog rt config --interactive false --url https://artifactory.myorg.com/artifactory
 ---> Running in 975540bce561
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
100   178  100   178    0     0    329      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   330

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
100   985  100   985    0     0    782      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--  3634
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0

 83 19.2M   83 16.0M    0     0  10.6M      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:-- 10.6M
100 19.2M  100 19.2M    0     0  11.4M      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:-- 19.9M
[Error] Wrong number of arguments. You can read the documentation at https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/JFrog+CLI
```

I've run the same commands on my local machine and gotten the same behaviour.

This is a command that we run in a CI pipeline and the last time that that CI pipeline ran was on 2018-04-19 (about 3 weeks ago) and I can see that on that occasion it succeeded:

```
Step 8/11 : RUN curl -fL https://getcli.jfrog.io | sh     && mv jfrog /usr/local/bin/jfrog     && jfrog rt config --interactive false --url https://artifactory.myorg.com/artifactory
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 1b0de0d85655
Step 9/11 : etc...
```

I can only infer that something in the jfrog CLI has changed in the interim. According to [the documentation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory) the command we're issuing:

```
jfrog rt config --interactive false --url https://artifactory.myorg.com/artifactory
```

is ok.

Hoping someone here can tell me what is wrong with this command,

Comment: Seems to be a bug in 1.15.0 and 1.15.1.  I have just tested with 1.14.0 and it works fine.  You can get the old version here: https://bintray.com/jfrog/jfrog-cli-go/jfrog-cli-linux-amd64

Comment: I raised a bug for this: https://github.com/JFrogDev/jfrog-cli-go/issues/165

Comment: jfrog rt config --interactive=false --url https://artifactory.myorg.com/artifactory

Comment: You need to add = right after the interactive option:

Comment: Yes I know. See the answer. Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is a breaking change in the latest version of the CLI. Details here: https://github.com/JFrogDev/jfrog-cli-go/issues/165